# Software that adds right-click drag option to move all files from tree up into one directory

Tags: windows-7

I want to move all files inside multiple directories at once by using right-click dragging in Windows 7.

There are 4 commands that I can use as a default function when I use drag and drop by right-click.

```
Copy to here
Move to here
Create a shortcut
Cancel
```

Is there a program that adds a command *Move all files inside (sub)directories (up) to here* to the menu?

For example when I have directories and files like this:

```
├─bar
│  │  3.txt
│  │
│  └─dir1
└─foo
        1.txt
        2.txt
```

I want to move files like this:

```
│  1.txt
│  2.txt
│  3.txt
│
├─bar
├─dir1
└─foo
```

Comment: Does it need to be free?

Comment: No, it's ok if it is not expensive and I can test the function before buying.